# Create std::vector by passing boost::pool_allocator as argument

Tags: c++, boost, allocator

I have a piece of code that will run in a loop and create `std::vector`'s on each iteration, so I want to use Boost's `pool_allocator` for efficiency. However, a library I'm using doesn't allow me to pass the allocator in as a template argument:

```
  std::vector<int, boost::pool_allocator<int> > v;

  // This doesn't work because the library doesn't support the new type with the custom allocator
  library::processVector(v);
```

So I thought of passing in the allocator as an argument to get around it:

```
auto pool{boost::pool_allocator<int>()};
std::vector<int> v(pool);
```

But that gives me a compile error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<int>::vector(int, boost::pool_allocator<int>&)’
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do this. The allocator used for the standard containers must be passed as a template parameter. And If you do provide a different allocator type as a template parameter, the type of the allocator argument passed to the container's constructor must either exactly match or be implicitly convertible to the allocator template parameter, so it should be:

```
 typedef boost::pool_allocator<int> pool;
 std::vector<int, pool> v(pool);
```

Comment: Hmm, that's unfortunate. So I guess there's no way of getting around this except by fixing the library?

Comment: As far as I know, I'm afraid so.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a vector created on each iteration?

Typically, you create vector outside the loop and `.clear()` it on each iteration. This enables reuse for already allocated memory.

Of course, this will not help in every situation. For example, if that library moves out from vector by assigning it to another by `std::move()` or `.swap()`, this wouldn't help.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, the loop is run in parallel so I can't predict exactly how much memory I need.